# Hammer.js - swipe right to delete?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, gestures

I'm working on a web app, and i'd like to use hammer.js to create the "swipe right to delete" effects.

Now, this effect it's not really a "swipe", but i think it is more like a drag right to delete, as that's the impression i have when i'm using any app on my mobile. Anyway, as a proof of concepts, i tried using this hammer.js example:

**HTML**

```
<ol>
<li style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); touch-action: none;">Swipe right to delete →
<li style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); touch-action: none;">Swipe right to delete →
</ol>
```

**JS:**

```
var test = {};
test.prepareForTouches = function () {

    function dragElement(event) {
        var elementToDrag = event.target;
        elementToDrag.style.left = event.gesture.deltaX + 'px';
    };

    function deleteElement(event) {
        var elementToDelete = event.target;
        event.gesture.stopDetect();
        elementToDelete.style.display = 'none';
    };

    function resetElement(event) {
        var elementToReset = event.target;
        elementToReset.style.left = 0;
    };

    var swipeOptions = {dragLockToAxis: true, dragBlockHorizontal: true};

    function initTouchListeners(touchableElement) {
        var touchControl = new Hammer(touchableElement, swipeOptions);
        touchControl.on("dragright", dragElement)
                .on("swiperight", deleteElement)
                .on("release", resetElement);
    };

    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i += 1) {
        initTouchListeners(listItems[i]);
    }
}
test.prepareForTouchesWhenReady = function () {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test.prepareForTouches);
};
test.prepareForTouchesWhenReady();
```

and it's working, as you can see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyMQVQ

The only problem i've got, it that i'd like to use hammer.js **v2**, and not the **v1** as the above example uses. On the new version, it seams like there's drag event to use, and here comes my problem. What can i use instead to create an effect similar to the one showed above?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.webdevbreak.com/episodes/touch-gestures-hammerjs this should help